# External XAMPP Access With Modem

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, xampp

I'm trying to create a live web server on my Windows 8.1 computer.

1. I am connected directly to my modem using ethernet (I do have a wireless router) but I am not connected to it on this computer (desktop).
2. I have XAMPP working and my website appears at `http://localhost/home`

However, if I put in my IP from `www.whatismyip.com` it does not load my web server.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Port Forwarding for Port 80 to your Computers local IP Address. There should be a Admin Panel for your Router (normally the Gateway - check out with Start - Run - cmd -> then insert "ipconfig" and check out the Gateway.

And i guess in XAMPP the Internet Access is blocked. But this is a simple Apache Server, so you need to open your httpd.conf File (Should be: “c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf)

Search here for:

There should be a "Deny from all" - add a # in Front to deactivate that rule.

Restart your Xampp and it should work.

Here you find more Information about Port-Forwarding:

https://managewp.com/how-to-access-a-local-website-from-internet-with-port-forwarding

Any maybe you will also need to activate Port 80 on your Firewall (depends on your Configuration)

Comment: There is no Deny all :s.... http://pastebin.com/xFdY6hjH There is a pastie of my file. I have already portforwarded on my static ip address. I decided to plug back into my wireless router. Also, my windows firewall is turned off.

Comment: So then Apache is already configurated for external Access. Have you already set your Port Forwarding? What happens if you enter your external IP Adress from another Computer?

Comment: I just checked on my iPhone which is connected to 3G. The page is just white, which I assumes means it can't load it. I have also used canyouseeme.org and it says it cannot see my service on port 80. Honestly, I think my ISP blocked port 80. Edit: By the way, this XAMPP installation is brand new (downloaded today) and unmodified.

Comment: Check your Firewall settings too. Did you already set up the Port Forwarding (this is really important!)

Comment: I have already portforwarded on port 80, and my firewall is off.

Answer (score 0):

You need a method of telling request sent to your public ip to be forwarded to the private ip of  the web server. Try logging into you device (router etc) and setting this up.